# Проблема с хранимой процедурой VK API

Tags: c#, json, vkontakte-api

Здравствуйте.
Создал хранимую процедуру для более быстрого получения списка друзей(для 25 пользователей одновременно) и записи их ID в массив.

```
var a=Args.users.split(",");
var i=0;
var result=[];
var tmp=[];
while(i<a.length)
{
    tmp=[API.friends.get({"user_id":a[i]})]@.items[0];
    result=result+tmp;
    i=i+1;
}
return result;
```

Задавая вручную параметры(в настройках приложения, прямо на сайте вк) все работает успешно ( на картинке: users=1,2)
[image: Задавая вручную параметры(в настройках приложения, прямо на сайте вк) все работает успешно ( на картинке: users=1,2)]

Запрос следующего вида:

```
https://api.vk.com/method/execute.getFriends?&access_token=aaaaaabbbbbbbccccc&users=1,23
```

В ответ получаю:

```
{"response":""}
```

В чем проблема,помогите,пожалуйста.Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо, ошибку нашел, неправильно отправлял запрос. В ссылке рядом `?&`,что неверно.И `&v=5.63` добавить.